# i have problem with give comment in post view in yii

Tags: php

i want to give the comments in the views form & i follow the function..

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('commentSubmitted')): ?>
        <div class="flash-success">
            <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('commentSubmitted'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php $this->renderPartial('/comment/_form',array(
            'model'=>$data,
        )); ?>
```

but now it show an error....
'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given'

my '_form.php' under  'comment' is

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'comment-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'content'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'content',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'content'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'author'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'author',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'author'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with yii's  'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given' is that we don't know what is causing this error.

I have made this crude change yii/web/helpers/CHTML.php:
`public static function encode($text)
    {
        if (is_object($text)){
          echo __FILE__ ." ".__LINE__;
          var_dump($text);
          die(" This is an object, and it must be string!");
        }
        else
          return htmlspecialchars($text,ENT_QUOTES,Yii::app()->charset);
    }`

So at least I know what object has been sent to that method.

Answer (score 0):

ouch, dont change core classes.

Yii active record model is glued to your database table. one possible reason for this warning message is that your db table does not contain all columns you are trying to make available in your form.

just guessing :)